# 'CREATE CREDENTIAL' is not supported in this version of SQL Server - Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sql-database

I am looking to set up my Azure SQL databases to back up to my Azure Blob Storage.

When trying to create the SQL credential with this code:

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL mycredential
WITH IDENTITY= 'storageaccountname' 
, SECRET = 
'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageaccountname;AccountKey=8L
==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
```

I get this error:

```
Msg 40514, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
'CREATE CREDENTIAL' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

The version of SQL is:

```
SELECT @@VERSION AS 'SQL Server Version'
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Jun 11 2017 11:55:10   Copyright 
(C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: Here is an example of what a connection string should look like for database restore: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-get-started-restore#restore-the-wide-world-importers-database-from-a-backup-file

Answer (score 1):

Stop right there. As far as i can tell, you don't have backup/restore in Azure SQL database, you'd have to use import/export instead. Is that what you are talking about?

Back to the question, CREATE(server-scoped)CREDENTIAL is not supported in Azure SQL database, if you still wish to use credential in Azure SQL database, use [CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql) instead.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to get a backup of any of my Azure SQL databases, and then store on my storage account.

Looks like I have set up long term retention for the Azure SQL database backups.

Thanks for your support...

Comment: You can restore from blob according to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-get-started-restore

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using incorrect key (secret key) in this case. You need to review your Azure container.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Was running into same issue trying to create a credential. Following actions helped me resolve

1. On the container, create an access policy first and used it in Shared access token creation.
2. Use SA user on the database to run the command.

I think the SA user might be the issue in my case. But one of my colleague used the access policy method and created the credential successfully

[image: create access policy before creating shared access tokens]